# timer also offline

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this as a timer that counts down from  55 minutes to 0. It works fine but when i disconnect the internet the counter will not run anymore. I think it is in the "countdownInterval() command but i don't know for sure. I also don't know how to fix it...

My counter:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    countdownInterval(
    // TO DO:  Zie dat je dit aanpast naar je wensen  !!!!!!!!!!!
    < ? php // UUR.
    echo($th); ? > , < ? php // MINUTEN
    echo($tm); ? > , < ? php // SECONDEN
    echo($ts); ? > );
});

// globals
var dateObj = null;
var targetDateObj = null;
var timerObj = null;

function doCountdown() {
    timerObj.setHours(targetDateObj.getHours() - dateObj.getHours());
    timerObj.setMinutes(targetDateObj.getMinutes() - dateObj.getMinutes());
    timerObj.setSeconds(targetDateObj.getSeconds() - dateObj.getSeconds());
    displayFunction();
    if (
    timerObj.getHours() == 00 && timerObj.getMinutes() == 00 && timerObj.getSeconds() == 00) {
        alertFunction();
        return null;
    }
    dateObj.setSeconds(dateObj.getSeconds() + 1);
    setTimeout("doCountdown()", 1000);
}

function countdownInterval(H, i, s) {
    dateObj = new Date();
    timerObj = new Date();
    targetDateObj = new Date();
    targetDateObj.setHours(dateObj.getHours() + H);
    targetDateObj.setMinutes(dateObj.getMinutes() + i);
    targetDateObj.setSeconds(dateObj.getSeconds() + s);
    doCountdown();
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}

function displayFunction() {
    $('#count2').val(
    checkTime(timerObj.getHours()) + ":" + checkTime(timerObj.getMinutes()) + ":" + checkTime(timerObj.getSeconds()));
}

function alertFunction() {
    // HIER KOMT DUS DE POPUP
    window.location.replace('einde.php');;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you be more detailed about what you mean by "disconnect the internet" Do you mean unplug the ethernet (or phomne) wire leading to your computer? Or do you mean that the code doesn't work as a file loaded from the operating system? It's a little difficult to understand why you want a javascript timer for a page that you can't get back to.

Comment: i mean that i test it on my laptop when disconnected to the www. And it will be running on a server who isn't connected to the www as well, but will have a network where tablets and laptops can connect to to browse to the page.

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads, it's calling `countdownInterval` which looks to get its parameters from a PHP script which I'm guessing that this page runs in. If you are offline, then the page won't be able to process the PHP (unless it's all being run locally). All those echo statements are generating output via PHP. If you want to run this offline you'd have to have the parameters in the JavaScript code already and not use the PHP chunk (the $tm, $th, and $ts variables).

Comment: It is all running on a localhost on my laptop and later on a server which is not conected to the internet. And i don't know how to use javascript for a counter. Becouse i need a counter for the site that counts down from 00:55:00 (hours:minutes:seconds) to 00:00:00

Comment: now i think about it. the problem is indeed with "countdownInterval" becouse everything after that isn't shown or run.
but other php on that site and php on other pages it likes to (on the same localhost and/or server) is working fine...